# Why does the Python function: type("This is a string') - return no results in the PyCharm IDE, but it returns <class 'str'> in IDLE and other editors?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I am learning Python, and have just been using editors so far, but now I am starting to move up to the PyCharm Community IDE. I am curious why, when I run the Python function: `type('Insert string here')` in the IDLE editor or in SublimeText or Atom, it finishes with `<class 'str'>`, but when I run the exact same function in PyCharm, it does finish without error, but it returns nothing to the console.

Comment: This is probably just the difference between a REPL and running a script, but please give more detail of how you're running this.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, when you say, "how you're running this," I am not sure what you mean; I am still new to Python, and programming in general. When you download and install Python from python.org, it installs a barebones IDE, called IDLE.app. It only allows you to type one line of code at a time, and has those three >>> carrots at each line. PyCharm is a much larger IDE. In IDLE, when I enter:  >>> type("any words") and hit enter, it prints out <class 'str'>. In PyCharm, if I create a new empty .py file, and I enter:  type("any words") and click Run, it just says: Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with PyCharm. The session with `>>>` is an interactive interpreter, sometimes called a REPL. You get the same thing just running `python` in your command line. IDLE can *also* let you edit and run a `.py` file, and that's different to the interactive session; in your command line, that's executing `python script.py`. This latter is also what PyCharm's Run will do. Also note that the "caret" is `^`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jonrsharpe said in the comment, the difference between the outcomes is probably because of the change from a REPL to running a script. I did some research on this topic, and I learned that PyCharm just interacts differently to code than SublimeText or IDLE.